# How to add a new user permission "Translate own nodes" ?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

Looking for this [Translation own nodes](http://drupal.org/project/translation_own_nodes) module but for Drupal 7.

The goal is to create a new permission to "Translate own nodes".

Comment: http://drupal.org/node/253157

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic method followed by that module should work (custom access callback + hook_menu_alter), but the code would need updating for D7.

From a quick scan of the code (so there may be other things that need updating) hook_perm is now hook_permission and hook_nodeapi has been replaced by serveral hooks (in this case only the 'prepare' op is used, so hook_node_prepare is the only one required here).

Comment: I'll try to update it myself